# How to withdraw Other ERC20 tokens besides Ethereum from my contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, remix, contract-debugging

I'm trying to implement something like this (which works)

```
function withdraw() public {
    msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance)
}
```

but I need to be able to withdraw ERC20 tokens other than Ethereum from my contract, is this possible? I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: A problem with the code snippet is that it is not permissioned so anyone will be able to extract ethers from the contract.

Answer (score 6):

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

function withdrawErc20(IERC20 token) public {
  require(token.transfer(msg.sender, token.balanceOf(address(this))), "Transfer failed");
}
```

See [IERC20](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol) for the interface code. Copy & paste it or [install it via npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@openzeppelin/contracts).